# Gradle: How to exclude an entire directory except one file?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to exclude all code in package `foo.bar` except for class `MyClass` for a certain Gradle subproject.

I tried to add this in `build.gradle`:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            exclude '**/foo/bar/**'
            include '**/foo/bar/MyClass'
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not work.

The related question [gradle: Exclude all - except one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916840/gradle-exclude-all-except-one-file) also does not work, because I am not trying to exclude everything, but only the contents of a certain package.

Comment: instead of excluding just include what you need? if I understand you have `myClass` inside the package and you want to just include that particular class, but nothing else?

Comment: @LazerBanana This is exactly what I don't want - to exclude everything else. My goal is not to alter the project's configurations in parent `build.gradle` files, only to exclude everything in `/foo/bar/` and include `/foo/bar/MyClass`. The way I am doing it right now is by excluding each file separately (but there are like 100+ files).

Comment: then you want to exclude the whole package but `MyClass`.. I'm not sure it's doable, maybe there is a workaround for this or some nasty hack but, the easiest thing to do is just to move this class somewhere else?

Comment: Yeah, meanwhile I am doing it but it is a huge project so there's a lot of refactoring (thank you IntelliJ for doing it automatically) :)

Comment: IntelliJ FTW !!